# Alarm Clock application help (AI)

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence, alarm

Ok, so i'm creating an AI for my self called Scot, now one of the features it will have is a alarm function to wake you up at 6 am or any time that the user will speak into the mic.
Now the thing I can't get is the alarm its self and how I would use a "Speak-to-Text" to set the alarm to a specific time. The functions it would have to do is,

1.speak into mic and have the "Speak-to-Text" and only get the integer of the the sentence so say someone speaks "Set an alarm for 6am" it ignore everything but the integer 6am. 
2. Next the program would ask if you would like to do this alarm in 24 hour intervals "Yes or No"
3. Lastly the AI would generate the whole alarm and would wake you up at 6am.

Please help me I have been at this for 12 hours now with no luck! I'm literally pulling out my hair!

If you need the code for my AI I can give you it.

Question: "Could you send me to a website that shows exactly this, or PREFERABLY put the possible way to code this in the comments!"

Thanks so much Joe Meyer

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: i tryed a timer and that uterly failed, but now im trying a windows task scheduler and i think it might work as an alarm function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I found a video on Youtube to do basically exactly what I wanted
[Youtube Alarm Clock, of which by using this video you can make it so you can use an ai](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adnvDw0sOLc)

Comment: This method also works for WPF as well, you just need to change it to (dispatcher time class).

Answer (score 0):

so you are creating a WPF application?
If you do so, you could try this [Speech Recognition MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683%28v=office.14%29.aspx).
When you have the whole sentence (you can use Regex to get the time) or the time you want, your AI can speek with this [Speech Synthesizer MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx).